# Styling paper-tab content

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I have concerning the content of `paper-tab`. Is there a way to style them in order to get two lines of content in each tabs?
Back in time, I would have created two `div, then used`::shadow .tab-content`to apply a`flex-direction: column``But now `::shadow`is deprecated... I've tried to replace it with the full selector as suggested on the chromestatus platform:

```
paper-tabs.tabs paper-tab #shadow-root div.tab-content
{
flex-direction: column;
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

I've tried using the mixin, with `style is="custom-style"`

```
.tabs{
--paper-tab-content: {flex-direction: column;};
}
```

doesn't work either

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymer allows element customization through [css mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-mixins)

Refering to the documentation for [paper-tabs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs) we can see that paper-tabs has a css mixin called `--paper-tabs`. In fact most polymer elements have a mixin named after the custom-element and this is the recommended way. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/blob/master/paper-tabs.html) we can see that the mixin is applied on the css `:host` tag.If you want to apply mixin within scope to all elements use `:root` tag. Otherwise replace `:root` with any class tag e.g. `my-class` and apply it to the element.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
        <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
        <link href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html" rel="import">
      
        <style is="custom-style">
          :root {
             /* Set custom property (variables) */
             --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: red;
             /* Set mixin */
             --paper-tabs: {
                 height: 200px;
                 background: teal;
                 color: rebeccapurple;
             };
           }
          
          /* Apply mixin via class */
          .my-class {
             --paper-tabs-selection-bar: {
                 height: 20px;
             }
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
           <paper-tabs selected="0">
                <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
           </paper-tabs>   
      
           <paper-tabs class="my-class" selected="0">
                <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
           </paper-tabs>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. But this does not solve my problem. I have no problem to change the tabs background or text though mixin. But for what Iwant to do (having tow lines of text in a tab), I need to apply a flex-direction: column which refuses to work

Comment: ok forget it. What I did wrong was to set my mixin in another selector than `root`. Now everything works. Thanks!

Comment: @SKMTH I should have been more clear that `:root` is not required. I just assumed you wanted to apply the mixin to every element. I have shown in the example how you can apply a mixin via a class or id.

Comment: Ok, I've tried and indeed, it's working now. Strange, I dodn't get why it wasn't working when I used the mixin example I've written in my original post. But well, thanks anyway, it's good to get the confirmation I was doing it (almost) right ;)